# HTMLTestRunner error：raise TypeError("{} is not callable".format(repr(test)))

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x

When I use `HTMLTestRunner` for Python 3.5，it shows an error.
I have changed the `HTMLTestRunner` for support python 3.5.
The code :

```
import pymysql
import pymysql
import unittest
import time
import unittest.suite
import HTMLTestRunner
import sys
def hell(a):
    print(a)
    return a
testunit = unittest.TestSuite()
testunit.addTest(hell('ad'))
filename = '/Users/vivi/Downloads/aa.html'
fp = open(filename, 'wb')  
runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(stream=fp, title=u'print', description=u'简单')
runner.run(testunit)
```

When I run it, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Applications/Python 3.5/……/B.py", line 30, in <module>
testunit.addTest(hell('ad'))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/unittest/suite.py", line 47, in addTest
raise TypeError("{} is not callable".format(repr(test)))
TypeError: 'ad' is not callable
```

What should I do to make the script works?

Comment: formatting, better grammar, more tags

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the *result* of the call to `hell('ad')` to your tests, not the `hell` function itself. Since the `hell` function returns its argument, it returns the string `ad`, which is not a callable (function or the like).

Use

```
testunit.addTest(hell)
```

instead.

What about that argument then, how do you pass that?
Well, there are ways to do that, but generally, try not to let your unit test functions take an argument. Thus, `hell()` should siply not take an argument.
If you code your unit test correctly, you'll find that you rarely need to pass it an argument.

Comment: 3Q,but the bug still here.    testunit.addTest(HellTest('testHell'))
TypeError: addTest() missing 1 required positional argument: 'test'

Comment: What is `HellTest`? And again, you seem to be calling the function when adding it, instead of adding the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

The line `testunit.addTest(hell('ad'))` doesn't do what you intend it to do. It doesn't tell the test suite to run `hell('ad')` later on. Rather, it calls that function immediately and passed the return value (which happens to be the string `'ad'` you gave it as an argument) to `addTest`. That causes the exception later on, since a string is not a valid test case.

I'm not exactly sure how you should fix this. Your `hell` function doesn't appear to actually test anything, so there's not an obvious way to transform it into a proper test. There is a `unittest.FunctionTestCase` class that wraps a function up as a `TestCase`, but it doesn't appear to have any way of passing arguments to the function. Probably you should write a `TestCase` subclass class, and add various `test_`-prefixed methods that actually test things.

Answer (score 0):

#### I had a right answer for my question, give the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import unittest
import HTMLTestRunner

def hell(a):
    print(a)
    return a

class HellTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.hell = hell
    def tearDown(self):
        pass
    def testHell(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.hell('aaa'), 'aaa')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testunit = unittest.TestSuite()
    testunit.addTest(HellTest('testHell'))

    filename = '/Users/vivi/Downloads/aa.html'
    fp = open(filename, 'wb')
    runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(stream=fp, title=u'不要生成error啦！', description=u'简单1112')
    runner.run(testunit)
    fp.close()
```

But, I do not know why add the class code 'class HellTest()'.The answer comes from a Chinese people whoes name is '幽谷奇峰'。Source code reference：https://segmentfault.com/q/1010000007427143?_ea=1345414